# How to implement a function with Python(Sympy), realizing the same as ToExpression in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

In Wolfram Mathematica, I can use ToExpression to convert a string to an expression, and evaluate the expression.

An example:

```
Reflection[expr_, a_] := expr /. a[l_] -> I*a[-l]
StringA = "Reflection[a[0]b[3],b]"
Output=ToExpression[StringA]
```

the result is ia[0]b[-3]

However, I don't know how to realize such thing in Python (or Sympy).

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

a, b, c, d, e, f=map(sp.IndexedBase,['a','b','c','d','e', 'f'])  
l1=map(sp.Wild,['l1'])
imagI=sp.I ## equals to Imaginary

def Reflection(expr, p):
    expr=imagI*expr.replace(p[l1],p[-l1], map=False, simultaneous=True, exact=False)
    return expr

fundict={'Reflection':Reflection}
pdict={'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d,'e':e,'f':f}  ##A dictionary used for connect the string to existed variable
mydict=dict(fundict,**pdict) ## combine two dictionary

StringA ='Reflection(a(0)b(3),b)'
```

How to realize the same work as the ToExpression does?

And more complicated case:

```
Reflection[expr_, a_] := expr /. a[l_] -> I*a[-l]
OAMHolo[expr_, a_, n_] := expr /. a[l_] -> a[l + n]

StringA = "Reflection[OAMHolo[Reflection[a[0]b[3],b],a,3],b]"
Output=ToExpression[StringA]
```

The output is -a[3]b[3]

For the python cases, I tried exec(), replace() but these don't work. So how to realize this case in Python?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sympify` converts a string into an expression. To use custom objects in `sympify`, pass them as a dictionary to the second argument.

Here is your example (I also fixed some minor bugs)

```
>>> l1 = Wild('l1')
>>> StringA = 'Reflection(a[0]*b[3], b)'
>>> sympify(StringA, mydict)
I*a[0]*b[-3]
```

Regarding `sympify` vs. `eval`, `sympify` uses `eval` internally. It is a littler smarter,

- `sympify('1/2')` will produce `Rational(1, 2)` whereas `eval('1/2')` produces `0.5`.
- `sympify` also automatically converts any undefined variables in the expression into Symbol or Function, whereas `eval` does not.
- `sympify` automatically evaluates the expression in the SymPy namespace, so any SymPy function will automatically be defined (with `eval` you have to either import the name manually or add it to a dictionary as the second argument)
- In the future `sympify` may become better than `eval` in terms of security (see https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12524). For now, both can execute arbitrary code, so they are unsafe to use on untrusted input.

The performance of either should be negligible. So I would recommend using `sympify` rather than `eval` to create SymPy expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found another way to do it, just using eval(). To be honest, I don't know which is faster or they are the same.

Comment: @XuemeiGu I have edited my answer with the differences between `sympify` and `eval`.